# $g^{(n)}(b)=(11+13i)^nf^{(n)}(a-b)\cos(n!|f^{(n)}(a+b)|^n)$ using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Bellow I'm listing an exercise from a past exam ,in University of Athens, in Complex Analysis.

a)Calculate $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }\frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+2x+2}:= \int_{-R}^{+R}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+2x+2} ,R\rightarrow \infty ,a\in \mathbb{R^+} $$ Does the the integral absolutely converges ?

b)**Prove or Dispove** that for every $f$ entire function in $ \mathbb{C} $ and for every $a,b$ in \mathbb{C} there exists an entire function $g$ such as $$g^{(n)}(b)=(11+13i)^nf^{(n)}(a-b)\cos(n!|f^{(n)}(a+b)|^n) , $$ where $n$ signifies the n times $f$ has been differentiated.

I have calculated the integral but I'm stuck on part b and I don't really know how to proceed , my intuition says that using Cauchy's integral formula for derivatives will help but I really don't know in what way. Every piece of help or tip would be greatly appreciated !I'm giving bellow my take on the integral, thank you all in advance !

We know that $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$ from Eulers formula and so by solving $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }\frac{x(\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax))}{x^2+2x+2}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }\frac{xe^{iax}}{x^2+2x+2}$ with the usage of a lemma that states that for every $f=\frac{P}{Q}$ ,where $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials and if  $degQ\geq degP+1$ ,while $Q$ has no real roots the formula :
$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }f(x)e^{lx}dx=\pm 2\pi i\sum_{1\leq k\leq n}Res(f(z)e^{ilz},z_k),l\in\mathbb{R}$   can be used. We then conclude that the integral in question is calculated to be the imaginary part of   $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }\frac{x(\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax))}{x^2+2x+2}$
and thus $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }\frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+2x+2}=\sqrt{2}\pi( \cos(-3\pi/4)+\sin(3\pi/4)$$

Comment: for the integral you have to be careful as only the upper half plane zeroes count for the residue since you apply Cauchy to the domain consisting of the segment from $-R$ to $R$ and the upper half plane semicircle of radius $R$ as $a>0$ implies the integral with $e^{iax}$ is convergent there but not in the lower half plane; for the second part the statement is a bit confusing (eg what is $n$, what is exactly the expression inside the cosine) but if it's absolute value inside the cosine and $n$ is fixed, one can fix $b$ eg $b=0$ and easily get a contradiction by letting $a$ vary

Comment: Yeah I used the residue which is positive since a is positve , i didn't note it . As for part b n signifies the n times f (or g) has been differentiated , I will edit the post